# Random Integers Printing in a Different File

Tags: python, function, file-handling

So I was trying to create a program in which random numbers print in a different file. I then try to find the mode of those numbers.

```py
        import statistics as stat
        import random

        def mean(list_x):
           '''This is the function to find the average of a list of numbers'''

           total = 0.0
   
           for i in list_x:
             total = total + i
           final = total/len(list_x)
           return final

        list_1 = []  
        list_2 = []  
        list_3 = []  
        list_4 = []  
        list_5 = []  

        def rand_nums():
          print("Column 1 Column 2 Column 3      Column 4             Column 5")
          for i in range(5):
            num1 = random.randint(1, 1000)
            list_1.append(num1)
            num2 = random.randint(1, 10000)
            list_2.append(num2)
            num3 = random.randint(200, 5000)
            list_3.append(num3)
            num4 = random.randint(1, 200)
            list_4.append(num4)
            num5 = random.randint(100, 2000)
            list_5.append(num5)
            final = print(num1, "\t", num2,"\t\t", num3, "\t\t\t", num4, "\t\t\t\t", num5)
          return final
  
        f = open("genericFile/storage.txt", "w")

        rand1 = rand_nums()

        f.write(str(rand1))

        mList1 = str(stat.mode(list_1))
        mList2 = str(stat.mode(list_2))
        mList3 = str(stat.mode(list_3))
        mList4 = str(stat.mode(list_4))
        mList5 = str(stat.mode(list_5))
        f.write(mList1)
        f.write(mList2)
        f.write(mList3)
        f.write(mList4)
        f.write(mList5)



        f.close()
```

When I run this, the value of the function rand_nums() appears as None. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `final = print(...)` is the problem since you then return it.

Comment: print doesn't return anything - it just prints. so you can't assign the result of print to something. you could just do `final = "".join([num1, "\t", ...])`

Comment: also, this is inside a loop, but final would be overwritten each loop iteration. so the lists wouldn't match the value of "final" which you are presumably trying to create.

Comment: should I just print instead of returning it?